# MATLAB: extract values from 3d matrix at given row and column indcies using sub2ind 3d

Tags: arrays, matlab, vectorization

I have 3d matrix `A` that has my data. At multiple locations defined by row and column indcies as shown by matrix `row_col_idx` I want to extract all data along the third dimension as shown below:

```
A = cat(3,[1:3;4:6], [7:9;10:12],[13:15;16:18],[19:21;22:24])  %matrix(2,3,4) 
row_col_idx=[1 1;1 2; 2 3]; 

idx = sub2ind(size(A(:,:,1)), row_col_idx(:,1),row_col_idx(:,2));
out=nan(size(A,3),size(row_col_idx,1));
for k=1:size(A,3) 
    temp=A(:,:,k);
    out(k,:)=temp(idx);          
end
out
```

The output of this code is as follows:

```
A(:,:,1) =

     1     2     3
     4     5     6


A(:,:,2) =

     7     8     9
    10    11    12


A(:,:,3) =

    13    14    15
    16    17    18


A(:,:,4) =

    19    20    21
    22    23    24


out =

     1     2     6
     7     8    12
    13    14    18
    19    20    24
```

The output is as expected. However, the actual `A` and  `row_col_idx` are huge, so this code is computationally expensive. Is there away to vertorize this code to avoid the loop and the `temp` matrix?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be vectorized using [linear indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/array-indexing.html#MatrixIndexingExample-2) and [implicit expansion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/):

```
out = A( row_col_idx(:,1) + ...
        (row_col_idx(:,2)-1)*size(A,1) + ...
        (0:size(A,1)*size(A,2):numel(A)-1) ).';
```

---

The above builds an indexing matrix as large as the output. If this is unacceptable due to memory limiations, it can be avoided by reshaping `A`:

```
sz = size(A); % store size A
A = reshape(A, [], sz(3)); % collapse first two dimensions
out = A(row_col_idx(:,1) + (row_col_idx(:,2)-1)*sz(1),:).'; % linear indexing along
% first two dims of A
A = reshape(A, sz); % reshape back A, if needed
```

Comment: I wonder what the cost is of making that indexing matrix... :)

Comment: @CrisLuengo Good point. I added a second version that avoids that using reshaping

Comment: Oh, that’s a nice one!

Comment: The second method seems to be the most efficent for my actual case with size `A(300,220,280) `and `row_col_idx (33,2)` and running the code for 1e4 times. Please see my other comment below.

Answer (score 2):

A more efficient method is using the entries of the `row_col_idx` vector for selecting the elements from `A`. I have compared the two methods for a large matrix, and as you can see the calculation is much faster.
For the `A` given in the question, it gives the same output

```
A = rand([2,3,10000000]);
row_col_idx=[1 1;1 2; 2 3];

idx = sub2ind(size(A(:,:,1)), row_col_idx(:,1),row_col_idx(:,2));
out=nan(size(A,3),size(row_col_idx,1));
tic;
for k=1:size(A,3)
    temp=A(:,:,k);
    out(k,:)=temp(idx);
end
time1 = toc;

%% More efficient method:
out2 = nan(size(A,3),size(row_col_idx,1));
tic;
for jj = 1:size(row_col_idx,1)
    out2(:,jj) = [A(row_col_idx(jj,1),row_col_idx(jj,2),:)];
end
time2 = toc;

fprintf('Time calculation 1: %d\n',time1);
fprintf('Time calculation 2: %d\n',time2);
```

Gives as output:

```
Time calculation 1: 1.954714e+01
Time calculation 2: 2.998120e-01
```

Comment: The relative timing of the two methods would likely depend on the relative sizes of the three dimensions of `A`, and the length of `row_col_idx`. Also, 2 orders of magnitude is way more time difference than I’d expect. What version of MATLAB did you use? Not Octave, I hope?

Comment: With the actual size of the matrix `A(300,220,280)` and matrix `row_col_idx (33,2)` and I need to run this at least 1e4 times. % Time calculation 1: 1.720272e+02 (@ASE methods), % Time calculation 2: 1.508412e+00 (@Nathan method), % Time calculation 3: 1.050692e+00 (@Luis Mendo method1), % Time calculation 4: 6.370173e-01 (@Luis Mendo method1).

Comment: FYI, I used version 2019b